# Instantiating error in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller, instantiation

I am working on a Rails app, wherein I have two models, i.e. a `chef` model and a `dish` model.

```
class Dish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :chef
  attr_accessible :description, :photo, :price
  validates :chef_id, presence: true
  has_attached_file :photo
end 

class Chef < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :mobile ,:password, :password_confirmation, :postcode
  has_many :dishes
  has_secure_password 
end
```

I (chef) am trying to create to a dish by going to the /upload url, whose view is

```
<%= form_for(@dish) do |d| %>  
  <%= d.label :description, "Please name your dish..."%>
  <%= d.text_field(:description)%>

  <%= d.label :price, "What should the price of the dish be..."%>
  <%= d.number_field(:price)%>

  <%= d.submit "Submit this Dish", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

I want the created dish to appear on the show page of the chef,

```
<% provide(:title, @chef.name)%>       
  <div class = "row">
    <aside class = "span4">
      <h1><%= @chef.name %></h1>
      <h2><%= @chef.dishes%></h2>       
     </aside>
   <div>
<% end %>
```

And, `dishes_controller` is:

```
class DishesController < ApplicationController  

  def create
    @dish = chef.dishes.build(params[:dish])
    if @dish.save
      redirect_to chef_path(@chef)
    else
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
```

But as soon as I try to create a dish from the /upload url, I get the following error in the dishes_controller:

```
NameError undefined local variable or method `chef' for #<DishesController:0x3465494>   

app/controllers/dishes_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

I think I have instantiated all variables, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
@dish = chef.dishes.build(params[:dish])
```

The `chef` variable is not instantiated. You have to do something like this:

```
@chef = Chef.find(params[:chef_id])
@dish = @chef.dishes.build(params[:dish])
```

This way the @chef variable is populated before you use it.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but I got this as an error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Chef without an ID):

Comment: Check your logs for the chef id param that are being passed to the controller. It is `params[:id]`, `params[:chef_id]` or something like it.